# How can I determine the primary display using python Xlib?

Tags: python, x11, xlib

I am working on a display configuration application and am trying to figure out a consistent way to determine which monitor is set to 'primary' using Xlib.

I am gathering properties using the following:

```py
info = {}
screen = display.Display(':0')
win = screen.screen( screen ).root
res = randr.get_screen_resources( win )
for output in res.outputs:
    props = screen.xrandr_list_output_properties(output)
    for atom in props.atoms:
        atom_name = screen.get_atom_name(atom)
        atom_info = screen.xrandr_get_output_property( output, atom, 0, 0, 1000).value[0]
        if isinstance( atom_info, int ):
            atom_info = screen.get_atom_name( atom_info )
        info[atom_name] = atom_info
```

I use Arch Linux KDE on both computers I've tried this on. I found an atom name labeled '_KDE_SCREEN_INDEX' on my laptop which seems to be what I'm looking for but this obviously won't be available in other DEs and in fact doesn't even show up on my other KDE setup. I think if I knew what xrandr looked for to find a 'primary' flag or whatever, I could figure it out in Xlib. I tried searching X11 documentation and Xlib's docs are incomplete. I'm trying to avoid using external xrandr commands in my app.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [protocol extension description](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/xorgproto/-/blob/master/randrproto.txt) and searching for `primary` suggests that you are looking for:

```
┌───
    RRGetOutputPrimary
    window: WINDOW
      ▶
    output: OUTPUT
└───
    Errors: Window

    RRGetOutputPrimary returns the primary output for the screen.
```